# Grails Dashboard says I have no Services

Tags: sql, grails, service, scaffolding

In the process of trying to troubleshoot my [Grails SQL Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55124795/4701396), I just realized that the default Grails Splash page says I have 0 Services. I figured this is a separate issue so I made a new question. I'm on Grails 3.3.9. See attached picture.[image: No Services] I'm using default scaffolded code here so my index page is calling my list method in the Service. What am I missing here? Service below (excuse my ignorance, I'm coming from Grails 2.3.11):

```
package TSTSupport

import grails.gorm.services.Service
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Service(TST_Customer)
@Transactional
interface TST_CustomerService {

    TST_Customer get(Serializable id)

    List<TST_Customer> list(Map args)

    Long count()

    void delete(Serializable id)

    TST_Customer save(TST_Customer TST_Customer)

}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but FYI... GORM Data Services are transactional by default so you don't need the `@Transactional` there.

Comment: I am specifically talking about GORM Data Services.  Regular Service artifacts are no longer transactional by default.  I haven't looked into it but I expect what you are seeing is that GORM Data Services are not included in the count in the default `index.gsp` page.

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of the _ in your class names

Comment: @JeffScottBrown the grails docs don't differentiate between a gorm data service and a regular service (from what I see anyway). I just used `grails create-service` like I did in Grails 2. So is there anyway to scaffold a regular service anymore?

Comment: @MikeW I can't make that decision alone (This same naming convention is used in a production version of the app). And out of curiosity, I did remove the underscore but it did not help.

Comment: "So is there anyway to scaffold a regular service anymore?" - Not without modifying the templates.  Recent versions of the scaffolding plugin generate a GORM Data Service.  That is best practice.

Comment: Scaffolding never generated a "regular service".

Comment: " I just used grails create-service like I did in Grails 2." - That does not generate a GORM Data Service.  That generates a regular service.  That is true in Grails 1, Grails 2 and Grails 3.

Comment: If you are saying that `create-service` generated the service that is shown in the question, that surprises me.

Comment: "the grails docs don't differentiate between a gorm data service and a regular service" - GORM Data Service capability is documented at http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#dataServices

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes (minus the @Transactional and the respective import) `create-service` generated the service in the question. I guess by your surprise then that's part of the problem. What is the command supposed to generate?

Comment: Are you sure?  That service looks more like it came out of `generate-all`.  Is that a possibility?

This shows what `create-service` does: http://jeffscreencasts.s3.amazonaws.com/bmoe.gif

Comment: Oh Jeff you're right sorry about that. I used `generate-all`. Using `create-service` gives me what's in your screencast. No implementations though so I'd have to write that myself. Anyway does that mean `generate-all` is broken then?

Comment: `create-service` uses the template from https://github.com/grails-profiles/base/blob/225a1ceb7cf7602641938f4648702ac819cd417d/templates/artifacts/Service.groovy.  `generate-all` uses the template from https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/blob/ce7f1241b7663f351e8d95b0e80e7d88207f6331/src/main/templates/scaffolding/Service.groovy.

Comment: No it doesn't mean `generate-all` is broken.  It is doing what it is supposed to do.  `generate-all` is supposed to generate a GORM Data Service with recent versions of the `scaffolding` plugin.

Comment: "generate-all is supposed to generate a GORM Data Service with recent versions of the scaffolding plugin if you are using the web profile." I understand that, but there's an assumption that once you do `generate-all` and run the app, you should be able to get to invoke the gorm service list action from the controller. I'm not seeing anywhere where this is spoken of otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JeffScottBrown, I realized that in Grails 3.3.9, the `generate-all` command creates a gorm data service which is different from a regular service (which is why Grails says I have 0 services). Using `create-service` is the way to go if you want the actual dashboard to recognize your services.